# Qt button continuous statement

Tags: c++, qt, loops, if-statement, button

i am wondering if anybody could help me with the issue i am facing. i have a button which controls a motor. im am trying to create a button, which can be used for calibration. 
the button i have is this:

```
void MainWindow::on_btn_Calibrate_clicked()
{
   check();
}
```

once the button is clicked,it should run a statment to check on the value `num5`
num5 is a switch, when it isnt clicked it is 0 but when clicked num5 is higher then 0.
so far:

```
if(num5 == 0){
    qDebug()<<"GO";
    qDebug()<<num5;
}
```

and

```
if (num5 > 0){
    qDebug()<<"STOPPED";
    qDebug()<<num5;
}
```

what i need is for it to run the first statement, then as soon as num5 becomes higher then 0, do the second statment. the problem is that when i click the button the motor does move backwards, however when it hits the switch i dont get the output "STOPPED". As i am guessing that once i click the button it checks both if statments at that instance. what i need is to click the button which will run the first statment until the second stament is true, then run the second one. i am guessing to do a loop, just every loop i have tried doesnt work or crashes the program.

thank you

Comment: you can use qstate machine http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstatemachine.html

Comment: Instead of using a loop I recommend using a QTimer, this concept is friendly with the GUI.

Comment: Hi i used a Qtimer and it worked thank you